# Selecionar 2 valores dentro de uma coluna de um Dataframe em Python e usar eles como "hue"

Tags: python, dataframe, gráfico, ciência-de-dados, big-data

Bom, o código abaixo é para mostrar em um gráfico de barras a comparação do volume de vendas por ano das plataformas Xbox One e PS4 apenas, e não de todas as plataformas. O data base está no github: https://github.com/malegopc/DSBD/tree/main/Datasets/Video_games

Clonando e importando o dataframe:

```
!git clone "https://github.com/malegopc/DSBD"

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('DSBD/Datasets/Video_games/venda_video_games.xlsx', na_values=['?'])
```

Código do gráfico:

```
sns.barplot(x = df['Ano'],y = df['Global'], hue = df['Plataforma'])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1.5,
                    bottom=3, 
                    right=7.0, 
                    top=4.5, 
                    wspace=0.2, 
                    hspace=0.9)
plt.show()
```

O resultado do código sai um gráfico de barras mostrando a venda de todas as plataformas por ano, mas queria comparar o volume de vendas por ano das plataformas Xbox One e PS4[image: saída do código]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!git clone "https://github.com/malegopc/DSBD"

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_excel('DSBD/Datasets/Video_games/venda_video_games.xlsx', na_values=['?'])
```

Você pode criar um novo data frame com a condição que você deseja, nesse caso que a plataforma seja ps4 ou xone

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Plataforma'] == 'PS4') | (df['Plataforma'] == 'XOne')]
```

E depois plotar o df2

```
sns.barplot(x = df2['Ano'], y = df2['Global'], hue = df2['Plataforma'])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1.5,
                    bottom=3, 
                    right=7.0, 
                    top=4.5, 
                    wspace=0.2, 
                    hspace=0.9)
plt.show()
```

[image: Grafico]